# Oracle SQL - set values for multiple parameters in the same alter_session_set_clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

It's said in documentation that

> You can set values for multiple parameters in the same alter_session_set_clause

but there are no examples how to do it.

I'm trying to make it work with a query:

```
alter session
 set nls_date_language = 'ENGLISH',  DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT = 360;
```

Maybe there's no way to do it in 19c at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. You just need to use the `space` as a separator and not a `comma`(,)

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'ENGLISH' DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT = 360;

Session altered.

SQL>
```

Even `Newline` as a separator works fine.

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'ENGLISH'
  2    DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT = 360;

Session altered.

SQL>
```

I know that `comma` can be used as a separator as per the oracle documentation but It is not.